# ERP bridge with Website

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, erp, bridge

i develop a website in PHP,Mysql that i will use it as an eshop and a need to make a mechanism in order to make it work with as many ERP systems as possible. I analyze the whole procedure but i need your help because i dont know if what i am thinking can work effectively.

Please take a look at my case study.

**Issue:** i face a sync issue with the bridge analyzation between ERP software and Website.

**Data:** I want to cover ,not a specific ERP software, but any.I have a website with products.

How are we going to sync the products between the Erp and the Website , in the case that we don't want to intervene in the ERP's API? the ERP just export the products in specific time intervals.

For example, a solution could that be:

**1.export all the products from the ERP, in a json string in a url, e.g. every 4 hours.
 2. a Task schedule in the webserver side will grab , every 4 hours, the json.
 3. check all the fetched rows and execute "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" on the database of the website?**

Problem: each time i have to check all the products that i bring from the ERP but that is a bandwidth problem , a time consuming problem and will also slow down the site.

I think the best solution would be to have an "Update (dattime)" field on each products record, but i dont want to intervene on each ERP.

Do you have any solution to suggest?

Comment: I think this a way to broad and unspecific question for a website like stack overflow. I doubt you'll have any luck with such architecture quastions. Even more so as they may be opinion based.

Comment: there is no reason to be more specific for technologies, etc.If i say that i need to sync SAP,sugarCRM,etc with my PHP site ,what would have changed? I believe that the logic in this use case is very specific.Who ever understands my issue can answer.